# Get Server Sent Sent data in php curl

Tags: php, json, curl, server-sent-events

I'm new to SSE, I have https url where it uses Server Sent Events (SSE). On some action its gives me a json data, Curl Example below which successfully gives updates on json data in terminal and also in java script it is working fine.

> Curl Command

Curl command working in Terminal

```
    curl --get 'https://api.xygfz.com:8100/update-stream/connect' --verbose
```

Above Curl command give me proper updates on new steam data.

> Javascript

```
URL = "https://api.xygfz.com:8100/update-stream/connect"
       source = new EventSource(URL);
       source.onmessage = function (event) {
          var data = JSON.parse(event.data)
          console.log('Received an event .......');
          console.log(data);
        }
```

> SAMPLE DATA FORM SERVER

```
 id: 1
 data: {"event_type":"CALL","uuid":"70f1-4898-847e-3f17ef219a64_0","customer_number":"+9888888","version":"1.0","type":"C_CALL"}

 id: 2
 data: {"event_type":"HANGUP","uuid":"70f1-4898-847e-3f17ef219a64_0","customer_number":"+88888888","version":"1.0","type":"HANGUP"}
```

Above Script also works fine and give updates on new steam data.

Concern is, i need to run it 24/7 automatically using PHP, here above if i close browser javascript wont work and in terminal if i close curl command will get stop executing.

Now i need to make it as a Php code where it should run automatically in the background, once a SSE push the json data it should be ready to request and save.

I'm trying something like this.

> PHP

```
 <?php
     header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
     header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
     header("Connection: keep-alive");

     $ch = curl_init('https://api.xygfz.com:8100/update-stream/connect');    
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
     $response = curl_exec($ch);       
     print_r($response);
 ?>
```

But im getting results as **Connection time out**.